# DBI prepared statement - bind hex-wildcard string

Tags: sql, arrays, perl, prepared-statement, dbi

I'm pretty new to Perl and I've been stumped by an error with DBI.  I'm trying to query for a series of characters defined by their hex values:

```
my @compare = ( '\'%\'+x\'0A\'+\'%\'',
                '\'%\'+x\'92\'+\'%\'',
                '\'%\'+x\'96\'+\'%\'',
                '\'%\'+x\'A0\'+\'%\'' );

my $fetch_bad_rows = $dbh->prepare( qq{
    SELECT B.* FROM ... AS B
    WHERE B. ... LIKE ?
        OR B. ... LIKE ?
        OR B. ... LIKE ?
        OR B. ... LIKE ?
});

$fetch_bad_rows->execute(@compare)

my $counter;
for( $counter = 0; $fetch_bad_rows->fetch; $counter++ ) {};
print LOG sprintf("Found %d bad rows\n", $counter);
```

Executing the statement this way finds 0 rows.  However, if I hard code the strings in the query, I get 437 records:

```
my $fetch_bad_rows = $dbh->prepare( qq{
SELECT B.* FROM ... AS B
    WHERE B. ... LIKE '%'+x'0A'+'%'
        OR B. ... LIKE '%'+x'92'+'%'
        OR B. ... LIKE '%'+x'96'+'%'
        OR B. ... LIKE '%'+x'A0'+'%'
});

$fetch_bad_rows->execute
```

I haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong with passing in the bind values.

Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which database are we talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the responses.  I did some more digging based on the info provided and found a way to get it working:

```
my @compare = ( '0A','92','96','A0' );

my $fetch_bad_rows = $dbh->prepare( qq{
    SELECT B.* FROM ... AS B
        WHERE B. ... LIKE '%' + UNHEX(?) + '%'
           OR B. ... LIKE '%' + UNHEX(?) + '%'
           OR B. ... LIKE '%' + UNHEX(?) + '%'
           OR B. ... LIKE '%' + UNHEX(?) + '%'
});

$fetch_bad_rows->execute(@compare)
```

I wasn't able to use 'x?' since the prepare call treated it as a table reference and complained that no table 'x' was found.  The UNHEX routine turned out to be what I needed, though, since it takes a string input.

Thanks again everyone

Answer (score 4):

The `?` in the `prepare` will make sure that everything is escaped. So if you pass in stuff that has `'` it will escape the quotes:

```
'\'%\'+x\'0A\'+\'%\''
```

Which can be more easily written as:

```
q{'%'+x'0A'+'%'}
```

will turn into:

```
... LIKE '\'%\'+x\'0A\'+\'%\''
```

And thus it does not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

The escaping that it's doing here is protecting you from SQL injection. Do any concatenation in the query itself, and only pass in the part that changes. For example:

```
my $sql = "SELECT x FROM y WHERE z LIKE '%' + x? + '%'";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute("0A");
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response.  I tried your approach, but the prepare call fails, saying "column 'x' is not found in any specified table"